# How to call a function while another is running

Tags: javascript

Instead of copying all the code I'm working with, let's just put an example.
I have:

```
<body onload="show()" >
//while show() is a : setInterval (function(){ thing=thing+1;},500);
```

Then in the HTML I have a button:

```
<button  onclick="thingPlus100()">Upgrade</button>
```

while `thingPlus100()` is for instance:

```
function thingPlus100() {
    thing= thing+100;
}
```

outside the loop.

This does not work.  So how do you in this case make a button that when pressed will sum 100 to the value of thing without breaking the loop?
!!!extension:
this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Index</title>
<link href="gameCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<script src="PlanetAndStructures.js" type="text/javascript">

</script>
<body onload="show()" >


<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="800" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">TGC*</th>
    <th scope="col">Radioactives</th>
    <th scope="col">Organic</th>
    <th scope="col">Metall</th>
    <th scope="col">Manpower</th>
    <th scope="col">Food</th>
    <th scope="col">Militar Power</th>
    <th scope="col">Economy</th>
    <th scope="col">Lvl</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p id="tottgc">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="totRadioactives">Loading</P></td>
    <td><p id="totOrganic">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="totMetal">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="Manpower">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="Food">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="MS">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="ES">Loading</p></td>
    <td><p id="Lvl">Loading</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Planet geology and info:</p>
<table width="800" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="128" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Gravity</td>
    <td width="152" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Natural ecosistem</td>
    <td width="142" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Radioactive</td>
    <td width="111" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Metal</td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Organic</td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Area</td>
    <td width="114" bgcolor="#00FF99" class="cent">Solar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="grav">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="natEc">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="radio">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="metal">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="organ">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="Area">?</p></td>
    <td height="23" bgcolor="#C6FFC6" class="cent"><p id="solar">?</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Planet indexes </p>
<table width="800" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Indexes</td>
    <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">Resource production</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Fuel</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Industry</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Ecosistem</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Research</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Anarchy</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Production</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" class="cent">Construction</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">Food</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">Radioactive</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">Organic</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">Metals</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">Energy </td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF6600" class="cent">TGC's</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="23" bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="FI">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="II">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="EI">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="RI">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="AI">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="PI">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFCE" class="cent"><p id="CI">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC6A4" class="cent"><p id="Fp";</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC6A4" class="cent"><p id="Rp">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC6A4" class="cent"><p id="Op">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC6A4" class="cent"><p id="Mp">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC6A4" class="cent"><p id="E">?</p></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC6A4" class="cent"><p id="TGCp">?</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Planet structures </p><table width="800" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="126" height="42">Solar plants</td>
    <td width="423">Encreases planet energy by solar index.<br /><span id="lvlCostSol">
      ?</span></td>
    <td width="151">Energy+</td>

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    //Im working with this button now---------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    <td width="72"><p id="butSol"><button  onclick="SolarLvlPlus()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plutonium plants</td>
    <td>Encreases planet energy by fuel index (needs radioactives to run)<br /><span id="lvlCostPlut">?</span></td>
    <td><p>Energy++; radioactives-</p>
    <p>Ecosystem --</p></td>
    <td><p id="butPlut"><button  onclick="plutonLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="46">Mines</td>
    <td>Encreases planet resource mining by industry index.<br /><span id="lvlCostMin">?</span></td>
    <td><p>[Metal, Organic, Radioactive ]+;<br />
    Ecosystem--</p></td>
    <td><p id="butMin"><button  onclick="minesLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Urbanitzations</td>
    <td>Encreases planet manpower growth by industry index.<br /><span id="lvlCostUrb">?</span></td>
    <td>Manpower + ;Ecosystem-</td>
    <td><p id="butUrb"><button  onclick="UrbanLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Storage Facilities</td>
    <td>Encreases planet resource storages by industry index.<br /><span id="lvlCostStor">?</span></td>
    <td>Estorage+</td>
    <td><p id="butStor"><button  onclick="storageLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="51">Food productors</td>
    <td>Encreases food production by ecosistem Index.<br /> <span id="lvlCostFood">?</span></td>
    <td>Food +</td>
    <td><p id="butFood"><button  onclick="foodProdLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>General Factories</td>
    <td>Encreases Industry and construction Index.<br /><span id="lvlCostFac">?</span></td>
    <td>Industry+; Construction +, Anarchy +;</td>
    <td><p id="butInd"><button  onclick="industryLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Markets</td>
    <td>Encreases TGC production.<br /><span id="lvlCostMar">?</span></td>
    <td>TGC+</td>
    <td><p id="butMark"><button  onclick="marketLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Space industries</td>
    <td>Encreases  production Index.<br /><span id="lvlCostSpc">?</span></td>
    <td>Production +</td>
    <td><p id="butSpaInd"><button  onclick="spaceIndLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ecosistem modulators</td>
    <td>encreases Ecosistem Index.<br /><span id="lvlCostEco">?</span></td>
    <td>Ecosystem ++</td>
    <td><p id="butEco"><button  onclick="ecoModLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="23">Artificial nutrishment</td>
    <td>encreases food production by research and industrial Index.<br /><span id="lvlCostArtF">?</span></td>
    <td>Food ++; Anarchy +</td>
    <td><p id="butArtNut"><button  onclick="artNutLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Order centers
    </td>
    <td>Decreases Anarchy Index.<br /><span id="lvlCostOrd">?</span></td>
    <td>Anarchy --</td>
    <td><p id="butOrd"><button  onclick="OrderLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Particle accelerators</td>
    <td>produces radioactive materials.<br /> <span id="lvlCostPart">?</span></td>
    <td>Fuel ++, Ecosystem-</td>
    <td><p id="butPart"><button  onclick="particleLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Geomorph</td>
    <td>increases usable area.<br /><span id="lvlCostGeoM">?</span></td>
    <td>Area+, Ecosystem -</td>
    <td><p id="butGeo"><button  onclick="geomorphLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Science Investments</td>
    <td>Increase research index.<br /><span id="lvlCostRes">?</span></td>
    <td>Research+</td>
    <td><p id="butRes"><button onclick="researchLvl+ ()">Upgrade</button></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="prodPH">?</p>


<p>*:Trans-Galactic Crown (money).</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</html>
</body>
```

and here is the .js:

```
    //PLANET UNMOBILE STATISTICS:
    var plaMetal=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+5);
    var plaArea =Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+50);
    var plaGrav =Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+3);
    var plaEco  =Math.floor((Math.random()*71)+30);
    var plaRad  =Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+3);
    var plaOrg  =Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+4);
    var plaSol  =Math.floor((Math.random()*250)+50);
    //STRUCTURE LEVELS;;
    var artifNoutrishmentLvl=0;
    var ecoModulatorsLvl=0;
    var foodProductorsLvl=1;
    var genFactoiesLvl=1;
    var geomorphLvl=0;
    var marketLvl=1;
    var minesLvl=1;
    var orderCenterLvl=1;
    var particlesLvl=0;
    var plutLvl=0;
    var scienceInvestLvl=1;
    var solarPlantsLvl=1;
    var spcIndustriesLvl=1;
    var storageLvl=1;
    var urbanitzationLvl=1;

    //OTHERS
    var buildings=0;
    var shipProd=0;
    var game=1;
    var solarConstr=0;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this is the variable!!!
    //INDEXES:
    var industryI=(((genFactoiesLvl*3)+(particlesLvl+urbanitzationLvl/2))/4)+1;
    var fuelI= ((industryI + urbanitzationLvl + particlesLvl)/4)+1;
    var ecosistemI= plaEco-(plutLvl*3)-(minesLvl*2)- urbanitzationLvl-particlesLvl-geomorphLvl+(ecoModulatorsLvl*4);
    var researchI=scienceInvestLvl*5;
    var anarchyI=(genFactoiesLvl*2)+ (artifNoutrishmentLvl*3) +urbanitzationLvl-(orderCenterLvl*4);
    var Production=(genFactoiesLvl*2)+(spcIndustriesLvl*4);
    var constructionI=(genFactoiesLvl*5);

    //RESOURCE PRODUCTION PER HOUR
    var foodPH=((foodProductorsLvl*plaEco)+ artifNoutrishmentLvl*10)*15/2 ;
    var radPH=((minesLvl*plaRad*industryI*2)+(particlesLvl*industryI*5)*20)/2;
    var metPH=((minesLvl*plaMetal*industryI*1.5)*19)/2;
    var orgPH=((minesLvl*(plaOrg/5)*industryI*3)*20)/2;
    var tgcPH=(((marketLvl*8)+industryI+urbanitzationLvl)*10)/2;

    //RESOURCES
    var energy= Math.round(solarE + plutoniumE - buildings - shipProd);
    var solarE =Math.round((plaSol*solarPlantsLvl)/10)+5;
    var plutoniumE=Math.round((plutLvl*fuelI)/3)+10;
    var radioactive =100;
    var organics=400;
    var metals=600;
    var tgcs =200;
    var food=500;
    var manpower =Math.round((urbanitzationLvl*industryI)/10);
    var energy= Math.round(solarE + plutoniumE - buildings - shipProd);
    //COSTS:
    //Metal
    var artifNoutMCost= Math.round(((artifNoutrishmentLvl^2)/4)*200)+ 500;
    var ecoModulatorsMCost= Math.round(((ecoModulatorsLvl^2)/2)*350)+80;
    var foodProductorsMCost= Math.round(((foodProductorsLvl^2)/20)*15)+25;
    var genFactoiesMCost= Math.round(((genFactoiesLvl^3)/13)*50)+50;
    var geomorphMCost= Math.round(((geomorphLvl^2)/5)*250)+500;
    var marketMCost= Math.round(((marketLvl^2)/10)*45)+54;
    var minesMCost= Math.round(((minesLvl^3)/20)*60)+45;
    var orderCenterMCost= Math.round(((orderCenterLvl^2)/10)*25)+100;
    var particlesMCost= Math.round((particlesLvl^4)*50)+550;
    var plutMCost= Math.round(((plutLvl^3)/25)*12)+100;
    var scienceInvestMCost= Math.round(((scienceInvestLvl^2)/10)*25)+55;
    var solarPlantsMCost= Math.round(((solarPlantsLvl^2)/10)*20)+40;
    var spcIndustriesMCost= Math.round(((spcIndustriesLvl^3)/3)*55)+250;
    var storageMCost= Math.round(((storageLvl^2)/10)*12)+ 160;
    var urbanitzationMCost= Math.round(((urbanitzationLvl^2)/12)*25)+45;
    //ORGANIC
    var artifNoutOCost= Math.round(((artifNoutrishmentLvl^3)/3)*250)+500;
    var ecoModulatorsOCost= Math.round(((ecoModulatorsLvl^2)/2)*350)+280;
    var foodProductorsOCost= Math.round(((foodProductorsLvl^2)/10)*25)+35;
    var genFactoiesOCost= Math.round(((genFactoiesLvl^3)/15)*30)+30;
    var geomorphOCost= Math.round(((geomorphLvl^2)/2)*400)+600;
    var marketOCost= Math.round(((marketLvl^2)/10)*45)+54;
    var minesOCost= Math.round(((minesLvl^2)/20)*30)+50;
    var orderCenterOCost= Math.round(((orderCenterLvl^2)/20)*25)+50;
    var particlesOCost= Math.round((particlesLvl^2)*5)+110;
    var plutOCost= Math.round(((plutLvl^2)/50)*6);
    var scienceInvestOCost= Math.round(((scienceInvestLvl^3)/10)*25)+80;
    var solarPlantsOCost= Math.round(((solarPlantsLvl^2)/19)*15)+20;
    var spcIndustriesOCost= Math.round(((spcIndustriesLvl^3)/5)*40)+300;
    var storageOCost= Math.round(((storageLvl^2)/10)*12)+ 160;
    var urbanitzationOCost= Math.round(((urbanitzationLvl^2)/6)*40)+25;

    //RADIOACTIVES

    var artifNoutRCost= 0;
    var ecoModulatorsRCost= Math.round(((ecoModulatorsLvl^2)/4)*450)+40;
    var foodProductorsRCost=0;
    var genFactoiesRCost= Math.round(((genFactoiesLvl^2)/33)*40)+30;
    var geomorphRCost= Math.round(((geomorphLvl^2)/5)*150)+300;
    var marketRCost= Math.round(((marketLvl^2)/10)*45)+54;
    var minesRCost= Math.round(((minesLvl^2)/30)*50)+35;
    var orderCenterRCost=0;
    var particlesRCost= Math.round((particlesLvl^4)*110)+750;
    var plutRCost= Math.round(((plutLvl^3)/15)*42)+240;
    var scienceInvestRCost= Math.round(((scienceInvestLvl^2)/15)*30)+25;
    var solarPlantsRCost= Math.round(((solarPlantsLvl^2)/40)*10)+10;
    var spcIndustriesRCost= Math.round(((spcIndustriesLvl^3)/3)*55)+250;
    var storageRCost= Math.round(((storageLvl^2)/10)*12)+ 160;
    var urbanitzationRCost= 0;
    //TIMES:
    var solarTime;







    function show(){


             setInterval (function(){
            //Planet geology and info table:
    document.getElementById("metal").innerHTML= plaMetal;
    document.getElementById("Area").innerHTML= plaArea;
    document.getElementById("grav").innerHTML= plaGrav;
    document.getElementById("natEc").innerHTML= plaEco + "%";
    document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML= plaRad;
    document.getElementById("organ").innerHTML= plaOrg;
    document.getElementById("solar").innerHTML= plaSol;
    document.getElementById("Area").innerHTML= plaArea;
    //Planet indexes table
    document.getElementById("E").innerHTML= Math.round(energy);
    document.getElementById("Fp").innerHTML= Math.round(food);
    document.getElementById("Rp").innerHTML= Math.round(radioactive);
    document.getElementById("Op").innerHTML= Math.round(organics);
    document.getElementById("Mp").innerHTML= Math.round(metals);
    document.getElementById("TGCp").innerHTML= Math.round(tgcs);
    document.getElementById("Manpower").innerHTML= manpower;
    document.getElementById("FI").innerHTML=Math.round( fuelI);
    document.getElementById("II").innerHTML=Math.round( industryI);
    document.getElementById("EI").innerHTML= ecosistemI;
    document.getElementById("RI").innerHTML= researchI;
    document.getElementById("AI").innerHTML= anarchyI;
    document.getElementById("PI").innerHTML= Production;
    document.getElementById("CI").innerHTML=constructionI;
    //COSTS AND LVLS 
    document.getElementById("lvlCostArtF").innerHTML="Current Lvl: " + artifNoutrishmentLvl + "Cost: " + artifNoutMCost + "Met; " + artifNoutOCost + "Org; " + artifNoutRCost + "Rad." ;
    document.getElementById("lvlCostEco").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+ecoModulatorsLvl+"Cost: "+ecoModulatorsMCost+"Met; "+ecoModulatorsOCost+"Org; "+ecoModulatorsRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostFood").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+foodProductorsLvl+"Cost: "+foodProductorsMCost+"Met; "+foodProductorsOCost+"Org; "+foodProductorsRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostFac").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+genFactoiesLvl+"Cost: "+genFactoiesMCost+"Met; "+genFactoiesOCost+"Org; "+genFactoiesRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostGeoM").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+geomorphLvl+"Cost: "+geomorphMCost+"Met; "+geomorphOCost+"Org; "+geomorphRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostMar").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+ marketLvl+"Cost: "+marketMCost+"Met; "+marketOCost+"Org; "+marketRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostMin").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+minesLvl+"Cost: "+minesMCost+"Met; "+minesOCost+"Org; "+minesRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostOrd").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+orderCenterLvl+"Cost: "+orderCenterMCost+"Met; "+orderCenterOCost+"Org; "+orderCenterRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostPart").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+particlesLvl+"Cost: "+particlesMCost+"Met; "+particlesOCost+"Org; "+particlesRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostPlut").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+plutLvl+"Cost: "+plutMCost+"Met; "+plutOCost+"Org; "+plutRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostRes").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+scienceInvestLvl+"Cost: "+scienceInvestMCost+"Met; "+scienceInvestOCost+"Org; "+scienceInvestRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostSol").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+solarPlantsLvl+"Cost: "+solarPlantsMCost+"Met; "+solarPlantsOCost+"Org; "+solarPlantsOCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostSpc").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+spcIndustriesLvl+"Cost: "+spcIndustriesMCost+"Met; "+spcIndustriesOCost+"Org; "+spcIndustriesRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostStor").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+storageLvl+"Cost: "+storageMCost+"Met; "+storageOCost+"Org; "+storageRCost+"Rad.";
    document.getElementById("lvlCostUrb").innerHTML="Current Lvl: "+urbanitzationLvl+"Cost: "+urbanitzationMCost+"Met; "+urbanitzationOCost+"Org; "+urbanitzationRCost+"Rad.";

    document.getElementById("prodPH").innerHTML="metal: "+metPH+" organics: "+orgPH+" radioactives: "+radPH+" tgc's: "+tgcPH+" food:"+foodPH;
    //PRODUCTION ENGINE

    radioactive=radioactive+(radPH/7200);
    organics=organics+(orgPH/7200);
    metals=metals+(metPH/7200);
    tgcs=tgcs+(tgcPH/7200);
    food=food+(foodPH/7200);

    //this is what it should do when the button is pressed

    if(solarConstr=1){
        }else if(metals>=solarPlantsMCost){
        }else if(radioactive>=solarPlantsRCost){
            }else if (organics>=solarPlantsOCost){
                metals=metals-solarPlantsMCost;
                radioactives=radioactives-solarPlantsRCost;
                organics=organics-solarPlantsOCost;
                solarTime=((solarPlantsOCost+solarPlantsRCost+solarPlantsMCost)*500)/constructionI;
                setTimeout(solarTime);
            }else if(solarTime>0){
                solarTime=-1;
                }else if(solarTime==0){
                solarPlantsLvl=+1;
                solarConstr=-1;
                }

    },500);}


//here is the extern function

    function SolarLvlPlus()
    {
    solarConstr=solarConstr+1;
        }
```

Comment: Your over-simplified example should work. Please show the actual `show()` and `thingPlus100()` function definitions. (And note that you don't have two functions running at the same time here. JS is single-threaded; `setInterval()` calls your function every x milliseconds, but doesn't stop other code running in between times.) One possible problem: your `<button>` element is a submit button (by default, because you didn't specify a `type`). Is it in a form?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Where/when "thing" is defined?

Comment: hi,I am not sure but if you define "thing" as global variable athen it should work

Comment: I've read here and there that the hooking of the events were best done in the code. I quite agree.

Comment: @AnilGupta It is implicitely defined as such if it not initialised with `var`.

Comment: I agree it's implicitly define,I am not sure but  my concern is if you define "thing" as global with like var thing = 0; then show and thingPlus100 both functions are going to use value of "thing".

Comment: I have put the real code now

Comment: what are your trying to do with `onclick="OrderLvl+ ()"`

Comment: It will do the same as the solarLvlPlus() Ill change the name when I make the function orderLvlPlus(), that was just scratch

Comment: then what's up with the `+` symbol? also, your declaration of `solarLvlPlus()` is invalid. You need to write `function solarLvlPlus()`

Comment: @nnnnnn can be the problem the button type? if its so, witch type should be?

Comment: @basilikum the + its nothing, Ill change it when Im there, and thats true about the function, but still dosnt work

Comment: `<button type="button">` unless you _want_ it to be a submit button. Though if it's not actually in a form there's nothing to submit...

Comment: ok, then I have another issue: you are writing `if(solarConstr=1){}` which just assigns 1 to solarConstr and then evaluates to `true`. You need to use `===` instead. And I'm not sure if your `if` statement will do what you want even if you change that. I mean it's formatted strangely, so it's hard to say if that was intentional but  right now it would do absolutely nothing if your if statement evaluates to true.

Comment: i have changed if(solarConstr=1){} to if(solarConstr===1){}and still dont work<br> and what the if intend to do is that if metal rad and organics ar greater or icual to the cost of solar then do the rest.

Comment: its any way to put the three statements thogether? like if(metal>=solarPlantsMCost;radioactive>=solarPlantsRCost;organics>=solarPlantsOCost){}???

Comment: @basilikum why would no nothing?

Comment: @Kaahrl sure but that is really really super basic stuff. Please do yourself a favor and go through some tutorials about javascript first. Every basics tutorial will cover the use of logical operators like `&&` and `||` that you have to use to put your three statements together.

Comment: @Kaahrl and take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/WadAv/2/ that should clear some things up

Comment: I have mannaged to make it to do something, (not what I intended, but something at the end) with "&&" :<br>if(solarConstr===1&&metals>=solarPlantsMCost&&radioactive>=solarPlantsRCost&&organics>=solarPlantsOCost) <br> so ill take it from here thanks so much nnnnnn & basilikum

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that your JavaScript code is not really JavaScript. It's incredibly bad code (wrap those variables in objects, use loops instead of twenty selector lines, etc). It would serve you well to first clean that up. Also, `setInterval` is a fairly questionable function to call, since it has to be manually cancelled. If there's an error in the code you call on interval, you will be generating errors constantly. Instead, use a setTimeout:

```
function X(...) {
  doThing();
  setTimeout(function() { X(...); }, 250);
}
```

Now if there's an error, it'll happens once, and then stop. You're no longer flooding a client with errors. Nice.

That wasn't the answer you're looking for, but is really what you should be doing before trying to figure out your problem.

Comment: _"Also, don't use onload, it may fire before all the DOM elements have been built properly"_ - No it won't. The whole point of `onload` is that it fires after the whole page has loaded.